# P value for chi-squared goodness of fit of geometric distribution doesn't make sense from R fitdist

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit

Trying to teach myself R and found the following conundrum.  I wrote a script to simulate rolling a die and adding the value until a "1" is rolled.  This worked well (eventually).  The mean and variance matched with the theoretical (1-p)/p.  I took one of the runs of 1000 samples and tried to fit a geometric distribution using the R function fitdist from package fitdistrplus.  The fitdist seemed to fit reasonably with a "prob" estimate of .139 and std error of .004.  Graphs look OK.  I then ran gofstat on the output, and the Chi-squared p-value was 10^-11?  By the definition of how the data were created, it is a geometric distribution, so why did Chi square fail?  Or do I have a fundamental misunderstanding of the underlying maths?  I'm not using scripts, but just running commands from the console.  Thanks.

edit:  code added
Note: I started calculating the values, rather than rolls, then realized it came out to 4 times the rolls (4 being average roll on a d6).  Doh.  It was working so I left it in.

```
samples <- 1000
runs <- 10
vecAttacks <- 1:samples
vecRolls <- 1:samples
superAve <- 1:runs
superRoll <- 1:runs
for (j in 1:runs){
for (i in 1:samples){
  attack <- 0
  numrolls <- 0 ##numrolls is the number of successful rolls
  repeat{
    roll <- sample(6,1,TRUE)
    if(roll == 1){
      vecAttacks[i] <- attack
      vecRolls[i] <- numrolls
      break
    } else {
      attack <- attack + roll
      numrolls <- numrolls + 1
    }
  }
}
AvgAttack <- mean(vecAttacks)
AvgRolls <- mean(vecRolls)
superAve[j] <- AvgAttack
superRoll[j] <- AvgRolls
}
print("sup=")
print (mean(superAve))
print (mean(superRoll))

> source('~/.active-rstudio-document')
[1] "sup="
[1] 20.3182
[1] 5.0747

> swap <- fitdist(vecRolls, distr = "geom", method = "mle")
> swap
Fitting of the distribution ' geom ' by maximum likelihood 
Parameters:
      estimate  Std. Error
prob 0.1714678 0.004935428
> gofstat(swap)
Chi-squared statistic:  13.06858 
Degree of freedom of the Chi-squared distribution:  10 
Chi-squared p-value:  0.2198627 
Chi-squared table:
      obscounts theocounts
<= 0  172.00000  171.46777
<= 1  141.00000  142.06657
<= 2  120.00000  117.70673
<= 3   86.00000   97.52382
<= 4   99.00000   80.80163
<= 5   63.00000   66.94676
<= 6   65.00000   55.46755
<= 8   64.00000   84.03321
<= 10  61.00000   57.68592
<= 12  42.00000   39.59940
<= 15  41.00000   37.38888
> 15   46.00000   49.31177

Goodness-of-fit criteria
                           1-mle-geom
Aikake's Information Criterion   5346.514
Bayesian Information Criterion   5351.422
```

Comment: I think you will need to show us the exact commands you used so that we can verify you applied them correctly. That will also help us determine whether this question needs a statistical answer or if it is only about how to use `R`, in which case it can be moved to a better forum on [SO].

Comment: I have a vector w/ 1000 values, "n", that come from a randomly generated geometric distribution.  Commands used were:  z <- fitdist(n, distr = "geom"); and gofstat(z).  The gof gives me a Chi Squared stat of 73, and a p value latter of 8.1e-11.

Comment: How exactly was that geometric distribution generated?  Your question suggests it is based on your own code rather than a built-in `R` generator, so this could be an important detail.

Comment: The script looks like it's working.  It generates random numbers from 1 to 6 (using "sample) until it gets a "1".  It adds 1 to a variable every successful roll and then puts that variable into a vector cell when it hits a 1 [number of number X of Bernoulli trial failures until a success].  Mean and variance match the theoretical of 5 and 30.  Interestingly, I did the same thing in Excel with 25 columns and if statements and the fits were better (chi squared p value of .73).  I then re-ran the script with only 100 loops and got a p of .4.  It seems like larger samples does something strange.

Comment: @Rick - put all your code into the question, so that someone can copy and paste it and run it.

Comment: Is there still a question here or has the problem gone away now?

Comment: Yes.  I still don't understand why Chi squared gives me crazy p values with large samples.  Is that inherent in the function (like the AD test)?